# ORACLE SQL select two table where the same type

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table

-------table1-------

```
_name　_status
aaa　　　Y
bbb　　　Y
ccc　　　N
```

-------table2-------

```
_name　_type
aaa　　　AA
aaa　　　BB
aaa　　　CC
bbb　　　AA
bbb　　　BB
ccc　　　CC
```

Can I select to?

```
_name　_status　_type
aaa　　　Y　　　AA,BB,CC
bbb　　　Y　　　AA,BB
ccc　　　N　　　CC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select t1.name, t1.status,
       listagg(t2.type, ',') within group (order by t2.type) as types
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name
group by t1.name, t1.status;
```